# Convert Array of JSON to Array of JSON based on key in hierarchical structure

Tags: arrays, json, nested, key

Hi I have array of JSON and I want to convert it into hierarchical structure...

i.e,

FROM

```
data = 
[
    { Level:"0", Name:"A1" },
    { Level:"1", Name:"A2" },
    { Level:"1", Name:"A3" },
    { Level:"0", Name:"A4" },
    { Level:"1", Name:"A4" },
    { Level:"1", Name:"A5" }
]
```

TO

```
0 =
[
    { 1: [ { Level:1, Name:A2 }, { Level:1, Name:A3 } ] },
    { 1: [ { Level:1, Name:A4 }, { Level:1, Name:A5 } }
]
```

I want to group based on level, starting from 0 but higher level can be more than 2.

Comment: Without knowing what tool(s) or language(s) can be used, it is frankly impossible to answer this question. _i.e._ using a text editor, your fingers and your mind, you have already converted the data. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy): _.groupBy(data, 'Level')